# Commerce error on product stock reaching zero

Tags: commerce

I'm using Commerce Stock as all my products have specific quantities.
When I sell the last of an item it gets marked disabled and stock goes to 0, but it continues to display on the 'all products' view and the page generates the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 39 in search_api_ranges_minmax() (line 188 of /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/brevardguns.com7/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/search_api_ranges/search_api_ranges.module).

If I change stock back to one the error goes away.
Also, if I disable the product and set stock to 0 manually, it does not display on the 'all products' view and does not generate the error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David